# Count and list rows? pl/sql

Tags: oracle, list, count

I am trying to count all rows that meet a criteria, and then also have it list sequence numbers for each row so we can quickly identify those meeting the criteria. Ex: We know 5 meet criteria of Complete Response and we want to know there are 5 but also what those sequence numbers are. How would i write that in my query?

```
select 
  count(sf.protocol_subject_id) as responseCount, sf.BEST_RESPONSE
from oncore.sv_sub_followup sf
where sf.protocol_no = $P{pPclNo} and sf.best_response is not null
group by sf.best_response
order by decode(best_response, 'Complete Response', 1, 'Partial Response', 2, 'Stable', 3, 'Progressive', 4, 'Not Evaluable', 5)
```

I should also mentioned that this is one of 9 subreports compiling a larger report. Not sure if that makes a difference when trying to do this. I'm very new to pl/sql. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sample data and the output you'd like to get from that data would be very helpful here.

Comment: What is `$P{pPclNo}`? That's not valid in SQL or PL/SQL. ???

Comment: Does "sequence number" mean the list of "protocol_subject_id"s? Or do you simply wish to assign a sequence number to each criteria e.g. 'Complete Response' = seq no 1, 'Partial Response' = 2 and so on? A sample expected output would help to understand this better

Comment: Hi Bob, correct that it is not valid. We have to go through Jasper to SQL developer and not everything transfers well/correct. So I have to go in and change those but for this purpose it doesn't have a bearing on what I need so I left it for now just so you all could see the group and order by areas if needed.

Comment: Vishnud, yes sequence number = protocol_subject_id. Subjects are already assigned a sequence number by the system, we use it to link tables as these are unique.  Expected output would look something like this:  Best Response = 5 : ABC-001, ABC-002, ABC-003, ABC-005, ABC-006  Partial Response = 2 : ABC-004, ABC-007    Where ABC-### is the sequence number or protocol_subject_id.    Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right, you need to count the rows for each BEST_RESPONSE for a given PROTOCOL_NO, and also list the IDs (protocol_subject_id) of those rows.
You could use the [analityc function LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030), that concatenates field values over a group. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    best_response,
    COUNT(protocol_subject_id) AS responsecount,
    LISTAGG(protocol_subject_id, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (
        ORDER BY
            1
    ) matching_rows_ids
FROM
    sv_sub_followup
WHERE
    protocol_no = :protocol_no
AND best_response IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    best_response
ORDER BY
    decode(best_response, 'Complete Response', 1, 'Partial Response', 2,
       'Stable', 3, 'Progressive', 4, 'Not Evaluable',
       5);
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the delay, it's been a bit hectic the last few weeks. I will give this a try and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to obtain your results like the below

```
        SELECT   responsecount,
             sf1.best_response,
             sf1.protocol_subject_id
             (
                      select   count(sf.protocol_subject_id) AS responsecount,
                               sf.best_response
                      FROM     oncore.sv_sub_followup sf
                      WHERE    sf.protocol_no = $p{ppclno}
                      AND      sf.best_response IS NOT NULL
                      GROUP BY sf.best_response)rec,
             oncore.sv_sub_followup             sf1
    WHERE    sf1.protocol_no=$p{ppclno}
    AND      sf1.best_response=rec.best_response
    ORDER BY instr('Complete Response,Partial Response,Stable,Progressive,Not Evaluable',sf1.best_response);
```